# Outlook Redemption for EML to MSG Conversion in C#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-redemption

We are planning to purchase the license of RDO Redemption to achieve EML to MSG conversion. However, before purchasing, we are testing with the Developer version which is working only in debug mode because this version displays a message box when it is installed on any computer.

Is there any way to verify this, in a Web application that is hosted in the IIS server? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The distributable version will not display any prompts.
Also, since you are running under IIS, you need to make sure that the MAPI system (i.e., Outlook) has the same bitness as your code (most likely x64 unless you forced IIS into x86) - see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject for more details.